# GMF how to create different shapes for link decorations

Tags: eclipse-gmf

I want to create and apply different shapes for source and target decorations of a connection. I know that I have to extend the polyline class but I can't really undersatnd how it works. Could someone help. Are there any examples? I know that only a few people work with gmf and till now nobody has answered my questions related with gmf but please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to extend the Polyline class, just call the `setTargetDecoration` method (or `setSourceDecoration`) and pass the decoration figure as an argument. You could also pass different decorators based on some condition. For example, an 'arrowhead' decorator figure can be created like this:

```
PointList pl = new PointList();
pl.addPoint(0, 0);
pl.addPoint(-2, -1);
pl.addPoint(-2, 1);

PolygonDecoration df = new PolygonDecoration();
df.setFill(true);
df.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.white);
df.setTemplate(pl);
```

Be sure to remove the `@generated` tag from the modified methods.